# How to write Image Mosaic Generator

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm, mosaic

Task is following: how to create selected picture mosaic from large number of images.
My first shot would be using evolutionary algorithm. Where genotype represents mapping of original images to positions in mosaic grid, and individual is evaluated according to similarity to original picture. Actually in basic approach each tile can be treated separately so iterating through the grid and matching best image would be sufficient. But I don't know yet how to define similarity functions.
Naive pixel wise comparing (r,g,b) difference probably would be too strict. I think that some
image processing algorithms should be apply like histogram balancing to optimize similarity between subimage and region where we try to locate it.

It would be similar to genetic algorithm that creates [Mona Lisa](http://rogeralsing.com/2008/12/07/genetic-programming-evolution-of-mona-lisa/) resemble.

Sample mosaic can be found [here](http://click7.org/image-mosaic-generator/).

Comment: Your question title should be: How to write a metric function which compares image contents in terms of hue?

Comment: Do you think it's only possible way to cope with this problem?

Comment: Purely as a reference here is an online mosaic generator: http://click7.org/image-mosaic-generator/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I did that (but I stopped somewhere) Look at:
[GetAMosaic](http://sourceforge.net/projects/getamosaic/) It was a testproject to do some C again:-) So dont look at every detail there.

Comment: Can you give a short description of your solution?

Comment: It is a console based program that can be exectued in two ways. First is scanning mode. All images are scanned clasified by average (RGB) color and put into a database (sqlite). The second mode is rendering mode where an input image is processed and the image from the database are placed at the right spot. 
There are also other algortithmic things like random noise adding, mixing of original image and small images, and and and. 
But this is basically the algorithm.